# Need run a goroutine for WaitGroup in a function

Tags: go

I've read a pipeline article from https://go.dev/blog/pipelines.

I've tried to remove the goroutine that covers **wg.Wait()** but it turns out that caused all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

I really don't understand why.

```
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` is a blocking channel. You need to `return out` and let something consume from `out`, or else the `output` goroutines will block as soon as they try to write anything. If `merge` waits on the waitgroup (i.e. waits for everything to finish) before the consumer even has a chance to *start*, that's an inevitable deadlock.